# Working with cv::Mat as signed values

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I want to deal with `cv::Mat` values as signed float values. for example if I made subtraction operation I want the negative values to be stored as negative and also if I made a divide operation I want the the result to be stored as float. 
What is the best to do this?
Many thanks

Comment: mat.convertTo (mat2, CV_32FCn) for n channel matrix mat. or CV_16SCn) if you want more efficience but dont need floating points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float values in OpenCV are always signed (as they are in C/C++).
A `cv::Mat` with depth `CV_32F` is `signed float`.